# Edit Sudoers file to allow sudo rights to a AD domain group

Tags: 18.04, active-directory, groups, kerberos, sssd

I recently managed to get my Ubuntu Server 18.04 machine connected to my companies Windows AD. I am able to login with my AD credentials however I want to take it a step further...

This is the article I followed in order to get my Ubuntu 18.04 machine onto the windows domain, note I did not do any configuration on restricting ssh login to a domain group as I am still struggling.
https://www.smbadmin.com/2018/06/connecting-ubuntu-server-1804-to-active.html?showComment=1548915938955#c6716393705599388679

However....

### The goal of what I am trying to achieve is as follows:

- Add a line to /etc/sudoers file that specifies an AD group within my organization.
- This groups members should have sudo access on the Linux machines in our organisation.

### What I've done:

- I tried adding lines like :
- "nameofdomain\nameofgroup ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"
- And more.... However whenever I try to sudo with a user I know is in the group I receive the usual "...user not in sudoers... incident will be reported..."

What could be the reason for this? Is it perhaps due to the configurations I've specified when connecting the machine to the AD domain?

The full path to this group  is as follows:
- domainname/Groups/Elab/Elab-Level3

Here is the configuration for my files used to join the AD domain:

***krb5.conf***

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MYREALM
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = true
```

...... rest of file ........

***realmd.conf***

```
[users]
 default-home = /home/%D/%U
 default-shell = /bin/bash

[active-directory]
 default-client = sssd
 os-name = Ubuntu Server
 os-version = 18.04

[service]
 automatic-install = no

[mydomain]
 fully-qualified-names = yes
 automatic-id-mapping = no
 user-principal = yes
 manage-system = yes
```

***sssd.conf***

```
[sssd] 
domains = mydomain config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, ssh

[domain/mydomain]
ad_domain = mydomain
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities
```

I'm really hoping that someone here has the answer, I've searched many many threads and have not been able to crack this nut

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If group consists of single word then it should be sufficient to add following record to /etc/sudoers file:

```
%ActiveDirectoryUserGroup ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If group contain spaces then record should look like:

```
%Domain\ Users ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%Domain\ Admins ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
%Linux\ Admins ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Here "Domain\ Users" , "Domain\ Admins", "Linux\ Admins" is group name in Active Directory

Comment: Your answer is EXACTLY what I needed. I did not realize that it is not necessary to specify the domain followed by the group. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, however please note to anyone reading this, simply specifing "%ActiveDirectoryUserGroup ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" worked exactly as needed

Answer (score 2):

I ran `sudo visudo` and I added this line:

```
%linuxadm@mycompany.com  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

and it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

```
%MYDOMAIN\\domain\ admins  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

DOMAIN NAME is UPPER-LETTER, group name is lower-letter, Separator[\] and Space are escape by '\'.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what You're after by creating a special domain user group - `cansudo`. The reason I did it this way was to separate being able to sudo from being a domain admin, while also differentiating from the local sudo group.

Depending on whether You have default domain prefixed to users and groups, the line that will work is either:

`%MYDOMAIN\\cansudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

or

`%cansudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

I've been scratching my head about this for a long time and then decided to put both of these in just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Chris! The first style, `%MYDOMAIN\\cansudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, is the one that finally worked for me. I'm using a Zentyal (ebox) AD controller/fileserver. I couldn't give anyone other than the installing admin (me) sudo privileges, now I can.